# Magento 2: Add to cart button in category page with pre-selected attributes of configurable child

Tags: php, magento2

I want to create an add to cart button for a child of a configurable product in the category page.

I'm trying with this code where I add the super_attribute hidden fields with the attributes values.

```
<?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($attributeOptions as $attr){ ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_child->getResource()->getAttribute($attr)->getData("attribute_id")?>]" value="<?php echo $super_attr[$attr] ?>">
    <?php } ?>
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
    <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>" class="action tocart primary">
                <span><?php echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The result is (for example)

```
<form data-role="tocart-form" action="baseurl/product-name?options=cart" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="5858">
    <input type="hidden" name="uenc" value="abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd">
    <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[185]" value="10">
    <input type="hidden" name="super_attribute[186]" value="12">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="DDAAkjkkkkkkj">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action tocart primary">
                <span>Add to Cart</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But when I try to add to cart, I'm redirected to the product page with the error "You need to choose options for your item."

I'm working on the v2.3.1.

Do you have suggestions on how to specify the options for the add to cart in the add to cart button? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but just so you know, if your question doesn't pick up traction here, there is a [magento specific stackexchange site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/), I would consider posting this there as well.

Comment: Thanks @ZacharyCraig , I'll consider that in case I have no answers!